# how to add event listener (onScroll) to every element inside a specific div in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onscroll

How can I add onScroll event listener to every element inside a specific div? (e.g. div with class: "add-event-listener-to-every-element-in-me" as you can see below.

in the example below there are only 2 elements inside the div so off course i could just add it manually but in my code there are hundreds of elements.

```
 <div className="add-event-listener-to-every-element-in-me">
    <div className: "i-have-the-event-listener">
      <p className: "i-have-the-event-listener" ></p>
      <div className: "i-have-the-event-listener"></div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll

```
document.querySelectorAll(".add-event-listener-to-every-element-in-me .i-have-the-event-listener").each( () => this.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollEventFunc));
```

Comment: hey, and what if the children and grandchildren etc don't have any classes? what if only parent class is available and I need to add function to every element inside that parent?

Comment: Ok, i think i found the answer: 
const Navbar = () => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")
        const arrayOfElements = myDiv[0].getElementsByTagName("*")
        console.log(arrayOfElements)

    },[])